# Why is Javascript clearInterval not working on button click?

Tags: javascript

I have a timer program that counts down from 25:00 on "start" button click and is supposed to reset and `clearInterval()` on "reset" button click. When the timer reaches 0:00 the if statements all pass and `resetTimer()` is called which executes the `clearInterval()` which works in this instance. So in short: `clearInterval()` works when the if statements pass but not when I click the "reset" button. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening and offer a solution? Thank you!

```
//My Programs Code:
//Timer Widget
function timerStartReset(event) {
  var minutes;
  var seconds;

  //decrease minutes html every minute
  const minutesInterval = setInterval(() => {
    minutes -= 1;
    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
  }, 60000);

  //decrease seconds html every second
  const secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
    seconds -= 1;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    //check if timer reaches 00:00
    if (seconds <= 0) {
      if (minutes <= 0) {
        //stop and reset timer

        //**HERE resetTimer() is called and clearInterval works**

        resetTimer();
        //return start button functionality
        timerStartBtn.disabled = false;
        //add a star
        const addStar = `<i class="fas fa-star h2 mx-2"></i>`;
        timerStarContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", addStar);
        localStorage.setItem("timer stars", timerStarContainer.innerHTML);
        setTimeout(breakAlert, 1000);
      }
      seconds = 60;
    }
  }, 1000);

  //start button function
  if (event.target.id === "timer-start") {
    startTimer();
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }
  //reset button function
  else {

    //**HERE resetTimer() is called but clearInterval doesn't work**

    resetTimer();
    timerStartBtn.disabled = false;
  }

  //Reset timer
  function resetTimer() {
    //Reset to starting template
    timerMinute.innerHTML = 25;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = "00";
    //Clear minute/second timeout function
    clearInterval(minutesInterval);
    clearInterval(secondsInterval);
  }

  //start timer
  function startTimer() {
    //Change starting time and add them to page
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 1;

    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;

    //start countdown
    minutesInterval;
    secondsInterval;
  }

  //Alert for breaks
  function breakAlert() {
    //If 4 star divs are added dynamically
    if (timerStarContainer.childElementCount >= 4) {
      swal(
        "Great Job! You Did It!",
        "Go ahead and take a 15-30 minute break!",
        "success"
      );
      //remove all stars from DOM
      timerStarContainer.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      swal("Awesome!", "Please take a 5 minute break!", "success");
    }
  }
}
//End Timer Widget
```

```js
const timerMinute = document.querySelector("#minute");
const timerSeconds = document.querySelector("#seconds");
const timerStartBtn = document.querySelector("#timer-start");
document.querySelector("#timer-btns").addEventListener("click", timerStartReset);

//Timer Widget
function timerStartReset(event) {
  var minutes;
  var seconds;

  //decrease minutes html every minute
  const minutesInterval = setInterval(() => {
    minutes -= 1;
    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
  }, 60000);

  //decrease seconds html every second
  const secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
    seconds -= 1;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    //check if timer reaches 00:00
    if (seconds <= 0) {
      if (minutes <= 0) {
        //stop and reset timer
        resetTimer();
        //return start button functionality
        timerStartBtn.disabled = false;
      }
      seconds = 60;
    }
  }, 1000);

  //start button function
  if (event.target.id === "timer-start") {
    startTimer();
    event.target.disabled = true;
  }
  //reset button function
  else {
    resetTimer();
    timerStartBtn.disabled = false;
  }

  //Reset timer
  function resetTimer() {
    //Reset to starting template
    timerMinute.innerHTML = 0;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = 11;
    //Clear minute/second timeout function
    clearInterval(minutesInterval);
    clearInterval(secondsInterval);
    console.log("reset");
  }

  //start timer
  function startTimer() {
    //Change starting time and add them to page
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 10;

    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;

    //start countdown
    minutesInterval;
    secondsInterval;
  }
}
//End Timer Widget
```

```html
<!-- Timer -->
    <div>
      <span id="minute">0</span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span id="seconds">11</span>
    </div>
    
    <div id="timer-btns">
      <button id="timer-start">Start</button>
      <button id="timer-reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
<!-- End Timer -->
```

Comment: You never add `resetTimer` as a click listener on the reset button.

Comment: @Barmar I have a click event on the container for both buttons. When the event.target.id === "timer-start it's referring to the start button. Otherwise it's the reset button. I just console.log("reset") to make sure the reset button is calling resetTimer(). Is that what you were referring to or am I still missing the point?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question and tried my best to leave out extra code. Does this work for you?

Comment: I already posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables `minutesInterval` and `secondsInterval` are local to this function. So every time you call the function, it starts new timers and creates new variables. When the code calls `resetTimer()`, it's only resetting the timer started by that invocation of `timerStartReset`, not the previous ones.

It works when the timer runs out, because the countdown code is in the same scope. But when you click the Reset button, that function is a new scope and can't access the variables from when the Start button was clicked.

The timer variables should be global variables that can be accessed from any invocation. And then there's no reason to use the same function for both buttons.

```
var minutesInterval;
var secondsInterval;

timerStartBtn.addEventListener('click', timerStart);
timerResetBtn.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);

function timerStart() {
  resetTimer();

  var minutes;
  var seconds;

  //decrease minutes html every minute
  minutesInterval = setInterval(() => {
    minutes -= 1;
    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
  }, 60000);

  //decrease seconds html every second
  secondsInterval = setInterval(() => {
    seconds -= 1;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
    //check if timer reaches 00:00
    if (seconds <= 0) {
      if (minutes <= 0) {
        resetTimer();
        //return start button functionality
        timerStartBtn.disabled = false;
        //add a star
        const addStar = `<i class="fas fa-star h2 mx-2"></i>`;
        timerStarContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", addStar);
        localStorage.setItem("timer stars", timerStarContainer.innerHTML);
        setTimeout(breakAlert, 1000);
      }
      seconds = 60;
    }
  }, 1000);

  startTimer();

  //start timer
  function startTimer() {
    //Change starting time and add them to page
    minutes = 0;
    seconds = 1;

    timerMinute.innerHTML = minutes;
    timerSeconds.innerHTML = seconds;

    //start countdown
    minutesInterval;
    secondsInterval;
  }

  //Alert for breaks
  function breakAlert() {
    //If 4 star divs are added dynamically
    if (timerStarContainer.childElementCount >= 4) {
      swal(
        "Great Job! You Did It!",
        "Go ahead and take a 15-30 minute break!",
        "success"
      );
      //remove all stars from DOM
      timerStarContainer.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
      swal("Awesome!", "Please take a 5 minute break!", "success");
    }
  }
}

//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
  //Reset to starting template
  timerMinute.innerHTML = 25;
  timerSeconds.innerHTML = "00";
  //Clear minute/second timeout function
  clearInterval(minutesInterval);
  clearInterval(secondsInterval);
}

//End Timer Widget
```